# Wicked Gem, associated models param is missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, wizard

I have a Boat model and Location Model. Boat `has_one :location`, Location `belongs_to :boat`. I used wicked gem to update the models. But I am having an issue in `boat_steps_controller`'s `#update` action.

Here is my `boat_steps_controller`,

```
class BoatStepsController < ApplicationController
    include Wicked::Wizard


    before_action :logged_in_user
    steps :model, :pricing, :description, :picture, :overview, :features, :location 

    def show
        @boat = current_user.boats.find(params[:boat_id])
    case step
    when :location 

        @location = @boat.build_location

    when :picture
        @picture = @boat.pictures.new
        @pictures = @boat.pictures.all
    end
        render_wizard

    end

    def update
        @boat = current_user.boats.find(params[:boat_id])
        @boat.update(boat_params)
    case step
    when :picture
        @picture.update(picture_params)

    when :location

        @location.update(location_params)

    end
        render_wizard @boat


    end


private

    def boat_params
      params.require(:boat).permit(:brand, :year, :model, .....)
    end

    def picture_params
      params.require(:picture).permit(:name, :boat_id, :image)
    end

    def location_params
      params.require(:location).permit(:address, :longitude, :latitude, :formatted_address, :location_type)
    end


end
```

The problem here is that, in `#update` action, I update `boat_params` in every step. But in Location, there is no `boat_params` to update as it is a associated model. So I have to find a way either get the boat id from the form or put if statement.

Here is the `location.html.erb` (form for wicked gem)

```
<%= form_for [@boat, @location], url: wizard_path, method: :put do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :address %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :address,:id => "geocomplete", :value => "Ataköy Marina, 34140 Bakırköy/İstanbul, Türkiye" %>
     </div>
     <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :longitude %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :longitude, :name => "lng", :readonly => "readonly" %>
      </div>

    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :latitude %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :latitude, :name => "lat", :readonly => "readonly" %>
     </div>

    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :formatted_address %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :formatted_address, :name => "formatted_address",        :readonly => "readonly" %>
    </div>

    <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Finish" ,class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    </div>

<% end %>
```

It should normally send boat id as I use `[@boat, @location]`, the url becomes, `http://localhost:3000/boats/241/boat_steps/location`. But when I post this, I get an error of;

```
Started PUT "/boats/241/boat_steps/location" for ::1 at 2015-05-12 10:00:21 +0300
Processing by BoatStepsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"jJOEBSCe9WdcuMKiHeVnh9zFEYuu15L5tzIkNFo9cED7ToG0MHq8jqeGstq5krdRGnrNXayNTQI0fajjHsNGgQ==", "location"=>{"address"=>"Ataköy Marina, 34140, Bakırköy, İstanbul, Türkiye"}, "lng"=>"28.87443200000007", "lat"=>"40.971388", "formatted_address"=>"Ataköy Marina, 34140 Bakırköy/İstanbul, Türkiye", "commit"=>"Finish", "boat_id"=>"241", "id"=>"location"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Boat Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "boats".* FROM "boats" WHERE "boats"."user_id" = ? AND "boats"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 1], ["id", 241]]
Completed 400 Bad Request in 51ms

ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: boat):
  app/controllers/boat_steps_controller.rb:50:in `boat_params'
  app/controllers/boat_steps_controller.rb:25:in `update'
```

And when I erase `@boat.update(boat_params)` from `#update` action (which is wrong) but then I receive an error,

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `update' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/boat_steps_controller.rb:32:in `update'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just put an easy `else` condition as;

```
def update
        @boat = current_user.boats.find(params[:boat_id])
    case step
    when :picture
        @picture.update(picture_params)

    when :location
        @location = @boat.build_location
        @location.update_attributes(address: params[:location][:address], longitude: params[:lng], latitude: params[:lat])
    else

        @boat.update(boat_params)
    end
        render_wizard @boat


    end
```